# Exists name in database? Laravel

Tags: php, mysql, database, laravel, exists

I have a database table called `categories` in that table I have the fields:
`id`, `name`, `description` and `urlname`

I want to check in the `route.php` file if the url is correct:

```
Route::get('products/{cat}' ,function($cat){
    $objCat = new Category;

    if($objCat-> ??? ){
        return View::make('products')->with('cat', $cat);
    }else{
        return View::make('notfound')->with('cat', $cat);
    }
});
```

How can I on the place with the `???` check if the `$cat` variable exists in the `urlname` field in the `categories` table?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Don`t instantiate the Category object.
You can do the following:

```
$model = Category::where('id', '=', $cat)->firstOrFail();
```

and register an exception with a redirect

```
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\ModelNotFoundException;

App::error(function(ModelNotFoundException $e)
{
    return Response::make('Not Found', 404);
});
```

Also here is an article for error handling in laravel:http://fideloper.com/laravel4-error-handling

Comment: Can you give an example of the `route.php` file, because now I am in trouble with the structure of the route.

Comment: This doesn't really do quite wha the OP wanted since they wanted to return a special view called 'notfound' for this particular situation where the category isn't found.

Answer (score 0):

This would do what you want:

```
Route::get('products/{urlName}', function ($urlName) {
    $objCat = Category::where('urlname', $urlName)->first();
    if ($objCat)
         return View::make('products')->with('cat', $objCat);
    else
         return View::make('notfound')->with('cat', $objCat);
});
```

A couple of programming style suggestions... I would recommend avoiding abbreviations to make your code more immediately clear ("category" instead of "cat").  I would also recommend using a controller instead of putting your code in a function () block in your routes.php.  That would help you to organize your code better and keep your routes.php file simple, but also it would allow you to use route caching.